# Comparing Two Dicts to Make a CSV for Inventory Management

Tags: python, csv

### Update: The Solution

I managed to get the following code to work

```
import collections
from lxml import etree
## Up here is code for getting an .xml input file from the user, opening that file, etc. ##
## This part is in a for loop that goes over each order in the xml file ##
## This all would have an extra indent because it is under this: for order in root.xpath('//order'): ##
itemlist = []
    ## This part looks through the .xml file for the order it is currently iterating and puts the items into a list ##
    for element in order.iter('items'):
        itemlist.append ("%s" % str.upper((element.get('type'))))
    ## This part 'sanitizes' the order name from the .xml file for use as a key ##
    for element in order.iter('order'):
        ordername = element.get('name')
        strippedordername = re.sub('[/\()!@#$%^&*()]', '', ordername)
        allordernames.append (strippedordername)
        print strippedordername
        #print itemlist
        ## This bit compiles a shopping list of items in a special dict subclass called a Counter. ##
        ordercounter.update(itemlist)
        ## This part makes a dict with order names for its keys and their corresponding Counter of items as its values ##
        ordersdictsdict[strippedordername] = collections.Counter(itemlist)
zeros = dict((k,0) for k in ordercounter.keys())
for cntr in ordersdictsdict.values():
    cntr.update(zeros)

#print ordercounter
#print ordersdictsdict
key_order = list(ordercounter.keys())
print key_order
with open(out_file,'w') as fout:
    fout.write('Order,'+','.join(key_order)+'\n')
    fout.write('Totals,'+','.join(str(ordercounter[k]) for k in key_order)+'\n') 
    for ordername,dct in ordersdictsdict.items():
        fout.write(ordername+','+','.join(str(dct[k]) for k in key_order)+'\n')
fout.closed
```

The output ends up looking like this:

```
Order,Spam,Eggs,Baked Beans,Sausage
Totals,13,1,1,1
Order for Joe,2,1,0,1
Order for Jill,11,0,1,0
```

### What I Have

My script takes an input xml file and parses it, looking for order name and then order contents.  There can be multiple orders in one xml file.  I then have a [counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that tallies up all the items from all the orders and gives me a grand total shopping list.

Given these two sample orders:

```
Order for Joe: Spam, Egg, Sausage, Spam
Order for Jill: Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Beaked Beans, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam
```

The counter would look like this:
`Counter({'Spam': 13,'Baked Beans' 1, 'Egg': 1, 'Sausage': 1})`

I then write this to a csv file so that it looks like this:

```
Item,Count
Spam,13
Baked Bean,1
Egg,1
Sausage,1
```

### What I Want

While the grand total shopping list is nice, I'd like to expand my output csv file to also include a shopping list for each order name.  I don't care if order names are the rows or the columns.  I also don't really care if the cell for an item not in that order is a `0` or empty but I'll use `0` in my examples.

Example Desired Output with Order Names as Rows

```
Order Name,Spam,Baked Beans,Egg,Sausage
Totals,13,1,1,1
Order for Joe,2,0,1,1
Order for Jill,11,1,0,0
```

Example Desired Output with Order Names as Columns

```
Item,Totals,Order for Joe,Order for Jill
Spam,13,2,11
Baked Beans,1,0,1
Egg,1,1,0
Sausage,1,1,0
```

### Notes

I want this script to work on any input file - of course if the input only contains one order, then `Totals` will match that order name.  I have to first make a grand total counter (so that I have all the possible items for the order(s) in question) and then fill in the csv with counts from each order.  In other words, I can't start my csv file by writing the items to it hard coded because the next input file might have different items in the orders.

Comment: What have you tried? As it stands, your post is an "I can haz teh codez?" question, which will likely get flamed on SO. Post your attempt and we can help you figure out where it went wrong

Comment: I certainly won't deny that your accusation is correct - I am indeed asking for code.  I've mulled over some needlessly complicated solutions that I could never think of a way to actually get to work and if this question ended up with no answers after a couple days I intended to write up some of those far-fetched ideas.  Fortunately, the Stack Overflow community has shone through as more helpful than 90% of the Internet once again and provided some ideas without flaming.  Your point is a valid one, though, and I honestly wish I had an idea that 'almost works' to post, but I don't.

Comment: No sweat. I'm glad to see that you've gotten help. I've seen it happen multiple times in the past, where questions like this die very quickly, which is why I posted my comment, before my answer - so that you can post an attempt, even a very suboptimal one, just so your post doesn't get deleted before you got answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use a `Counter` for every line of the input file?

```
from collections import Counter
d = {}  
#*1* Alternatively, could use : d = defaultdict(Counter)
with open(inputfile) as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        for_who, items = line[:-1].split(':',1)
        d[for_who] = Counter(items.split(','))  
        #Alternatively, if using defaultdict at *1*, d.update(items.split(','))
        #This allows "joe" to register multiple shopping lists which get summed into 1

#get totals by `sum`ming your Counters values:
totals = sum(d.values())

#Now add a 0-dict to each of the dictionaries just to make sure they have all the keys
zeros = dict((k,0) for k in totals)
for cntr in d.values():
    cntr.update(zeros)

key_order = list(totals.keys())  #list for py2k
with open(output_file,'w') as fout:
    fout.write('Order '+','.join(key_order)+'\n')
    fout.write('Totals,'+','.join(str(totals[k]) for k in key_order)+'\n') 
    for person,dct in d.items():
        fout.write(person+','+','.join(str(dct[k]) for k in key_order)+'\n')
```

You may need to get a little more tricky to deal with quoting if your items can have commas in the names (Think `csv` module for that stuff), but this should give you a good place to start.

Comment: I think your 0-dict step was a key piece I was missing (and that some other answers seem to be missing as well.)  I already have totals in the counter I mentioned at the top of my post, but it is interesting to see a way to rebuild that counter from the output file.  So far your answer is closest to working for me, I think.

Comment: @Qanthelas -- Another thing you could do rather than add the 0-dict is to subclass `Counter` overriding the `__missing__` method and have that return whatever you want to put in the file if the person doesn't have a particular item in their order.  That would probably be slightly more efficient (and clean) at the expense of creating a new class.

Comment: I ended up getting a slightly tweaked version of your answer to work!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a csv.DictWriter to manage your output.

You will assemble a long list of Counters for each individual order, plus one Counter that contains the totals.

As you're reading in your inputs, process the inputs like this:

1. Add each of the items in the order to your "totals" dictionary with .update
2. Add each of the items in the order to the "order" dictionary by creating new
3. Add an "Order Name" key to each counter, with the order name
4. Create your DictWriter instance, with fieldnames being totals.keys()

Comment: That does seem like a possible process, although I think you'd have to add mgilson's 0-dict step to make sure each order dictionary has all the items in it as keys.  This does nicely outline one process, so points for that.

Comment: The "0 dict step" is managed by step 1. Since you're adding to a running total, everything gets added to the "totals" dictionary. Or counter, or whatever you want to call it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a nested [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) set to initialize at 0.

Suppose your input file looks like this:

```
Order for Joe: Spam, Egg, Sausage, Spam
Order for Jill: Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Beaked Beans, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam
```

Then, you can get both totals and individual order counts as follows:

```
answer = collections.defaultdict(collections.defaultdict(int))
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        name, _, orders = line.partition(":")
        name = name.rpartition(' ')[-1]
        orders = orders.strip().split(',')
        for order in orders:
            answer['total'][order] += 1
            answer[name][order] += 1
with open('path/to/output') as outfile:
    keys = sorted(answer['total'])
    outfile.write("Order Name,%s" %(','.join(keys)))
    outfile.write('total,%s' %(','.join(answer['total'][k] for k in keys)))
    for name, orders in answer.iteritems():
        if name != 'total':
            outfile.write('%s,%s' %(name, ','.join(answer[name][k] for k in keys)))
```

Comment: This seems to be hard coding the item names, something I specifically said I need to avoid (since the next input file might have orders with different items.)  Still, it shows a slightly different way of going about things than the other answers, so points for that.

Comment: @Qanthelas: check out the edit; completely data-driven code now

Comment: Too bad we don't have a `DefaultCounterDict` in the stdlib :p